Unbonded Boards with both axial and transverse end loads
In the case of unbonded cantilever boards undergoing a point end load, is there an analytical way to solve for the resulting deflection and angular displacement of the boards if we apply an axial end load to the lower boards as shown? From intuition the end loads would make the overall bending stiffness somewhere between fully bonded and fully unbonded cantilever boards.


This has been asked before on here, do check.

Can you point me to where this has been asked/answered? I have not been able to find anything that contains both loading cases simultaneously.

So easy: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/56316/10902

This is a related but different problem as the one you provided a link to, as it is a further application of that problem. That case has no axial loads.

So how do those axial loads change the behaviour? Have you summed the forces appropriately? At what angle are those forces applied? perpendicular to the end face? will that angle change as the boards bend more? Or are the forces only perpendicular to the faces prior to the bending load P being applied?

This is an example of how to force a column to buckle.
I go over basic considerations.
This system has to be checked for buckling and deflection. Then it has to be checked again for $P\Delta \ $ effect.
For deflection, one has to consider the combined effect of axial loading and lateral loading.
A member loaded axially acts as a column and will buckle under the critical load of
$$p_{cr}=\frac{\pi^2EI}{(kl)^2}$$

K is the effective column length 1/2 for a cantilever beam but here it depends on the friction between the two beams.
L is the length
E modulus of elasticity
I is the 2nd moment of are
C is the farthest distance from the beam neutral axis
$\sigma \ $ is the maximum allowable stress

If we ignore the effect of friction
the second beam would have to meet this condition
$$\frac{P/A}{P_{cr}/A}+\frac{\sigma_M}{\sigma_{m_{cr}}}\ =\frac{P/A}{P_{cr}/A}+\frac{P_{lateral}/3* L*C/I}{\sigma_{max} C} \le 1$$

$P = F_1$

The equation of combined axial and moment deflection
$$ y(x) = \frac{M}{F_1} \left(1 - \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{P}{EI}} x\right)\right)$$

$M =P_{lateral}/3.L$

These are the basic first steps. Then we need to calculate the $P\Delta \ $ effect.
In reality, the friction can be significant and the difference between F1 and F2 can matter.
